# Way to know when last AJAX call has completed in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

One of my pages has about 5 jQuery AJAX calls that fire off as soon as the page loads. I know that I can track each AJAX call individually and know when it is complete, but is there any way to track them as a whole? This way, I'll know when the last AJAX call is complete and I can signal a UI change.

I guess I could keep a running count of the number of "active" calls and check that number each time a call completes, but is there a more eloquent solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at the global [`ajaxStart`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxStart) and [`ajaxStop`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxStop) events.

Here's how I've used them:

```
$('body')
    // Set up loading animation for requests.
    .ajaxStart(function () {
        $(this).addClass('loading');
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('loading');
    });
```

Comment: Works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use queue/dequeue which are useful for any function calls:

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/api-queue-dequeue/

You could put your UI function at the end of the queue.

Down side is that it causes your functions to be synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax object has a method especifically for this: [complete()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) which is fired when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed).

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    complete: function(){
        alert( "action finished" );
    }
});
```